# Vectorizing code of looping through NumPy 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, vectorization

I'm currently writing a program that processes an image and returns the same image except some pixels that are identified as a certain feature (found via `truth_table`) are blackened. It works, but since the images are around 5000 by 5000 pixels, it takes about 1 whole minute just to go through this part:

```
image_DN_no_12s = np.copy(image_DN)
for y in range(y_size):
    for x in range(x_size):
        if truth_table[y, x] == 12:
            image_DN_no_12s[y, x, :] = np.zeros((1, 1, 4))
```

(The 3rd dimension in `np.zeros()` is 4 because I am reading red, green, blue, and infrared channels.)

I would like to vectorize this code so that it will run faster. I have tried using `np.where()` and boolean indexing, but I can't seem to find a way to make it run faster.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `img` and `truth_table` are arrays where `truth_table` is of broadcastable shape:

```
img[truth_table == 12] = 0
```

You don't need to explicitly create another axis of 4 channels since broadcasting handles it for you.